# it is possible to expand text to columns?

Tags: mysql

Having a jobs table with a field with name params of type longtext and with values ​​in the format key: value, anotherKey: anotherValue. It is possible through a query to expand these keys to columns.

For example having the following value in the params field

```
{
    "field964" : "Value",
    "field966" : "Value",
    "field967" : "Value",
    "field968" : "Value",
    "field969" : "Value",
    "field970" : "Value",
    "field971" : "Value",
    "field972" : "Value",
    "field973" : "Value",
    "field974" : "Value",
    "field975" : "Value",
    "field976" : "Value",
    "field977" : "Value",
    "field978" : "Value",
    "field979" : "Value",
    "field980" : "Value",
    "field981" : "Value",
    "field982" : "Value"
}
```

Could it transform the field into a result where each field corresponds a key of the text and the value is the value of the corresponding key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use a client programming language? That value is JSON, so you can use a JSON parser in PHP, Python, Javascript, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering, what you suggest is what I plan to do but I want to know if it is possible to do it in the database manager

Comment: Not easily. It's similar to pivoting a table, but even harder because there's no easy way to parse text like this.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 adds a JSON datatype, but I don't think it has any function to enumerate the keys of an object.

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to clear up this doubt. Thanks for your time. Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh... solved this task for you!

Here is SQLFiddle: http://rextester.com/XNFKU52341

Took your test data:

```
CREATE TABLE t20_table (value JSON);
INSERT INTO t20_table VALUES ('{
    "field964" : \"Value1\",
    "field966" : \"Value2\",
    "field967" : \"Value3\",
    "field968" : \"Value4\",
    "field969" : \"Value5\",
    "field970" : \"Value6\",
    "field971" : \"Value7\",
    "field972" : \"Value8\",
    "field973" : \"Value9\",
    "field974" : \"Value10\",
    "field975" : \"Value11\",
    "field976" : \"Value12\",
    "field977" : \"Value13\",
    "field978" : \"Value14\",
    "field979" : \"Value15\",
    "field980" : \"Value16\",
    "field981" : \"Value17\",
    "field982" : \"Value18\"
}');
```

Actual solution:

```
# generate range between 0 and N - number of keys
CREATE TABLE incr (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);

CREATE PROCEDURE xrange(value INTEGER)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE v1 < value DO
    INSERT incr VALUES (NULL);
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;

SET @keys = (SELECT JSON_KEYS(value) FROM t20_table);
SET @length = (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(value->"$.*") FROM t20_table);

# generating number range from 0 to @length
CALL xrange(@length);

# generate SELECT statement with JSON_EXTRACT
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('JSON_EXTRACT(value->"$.*", ', '"$[', id - 1,']") AS ', JSON_EXTRACT(@keys, CONCAT("$[", id - 1, "]")), '') 
INTO @query
FROM incr;

SELECT @query;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @query, ' FROM t20_table;');
PREPARE q FROM @query;

EXECUTE q;
```

Output:

[image]